# Convert time PST/PDT to timestamp using Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

**Background:**
I have the below table of data where I'm trying to concat the **order_date** and **transaction_time** columns to create a final **timestamp** column

**Problem:**
There is a PST/PDT string in the **transaction_time** column. I am trying to convert my final **timestamp** column(VARCHAR)  into a UTC timestamp

**My attempted solution that didn't work:**

```
select
  transaction_date
  , to_date(transaction_date, 'mon dd, yyyy')    as order_date
  , transaction_time
  , concat(transaction_date, ' ', transaction_time)   as timestamp
--  , to_timestamp_tz(concat(transaction_date, ' ', transaction_time), 'mon dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss am pdt')   as final_timestamp
from raw_db.schema_name.table_name
```

Please help?? Thank you!!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So PST and PDT are not valid iana timezone's which is what is expected by the [Timestamp Formats](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#timestamp-formats), so you cannot use the inbuilt functions to handle that, but you can work around it.

```
SELECT time
    ,try_to_timestamp(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS AM PDT') as pdt_time
    ,try_to_timestamp(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS AM PST') as pst_time
    ,dateadd('hour',7, pdt_time) as pdt_as_utc_time
    ,dateadd('hour',8, pst_time) as pst_as_utc_time
    ,coalesce(pdt_as_utc_time, pst_as_utc_time) as utc_time1
    ,iff(substr(time, -3) = 'PDT', pdt_as_utc_time, pst_as_utc_time ) as utc_time2
FROM VALUES
    ('2020-10-28 7:25:44 AM PDT'),
-- insert more rows here...
    ('2020-11-06 6:35:18 PM PST') 
    v(time);
```

shows two ways to get a unified UTC time from the two.

which could be shortened to:

```
SELECT time
    ,coalesce(dateadd('hour',7, try_to_timestamp(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS AM PDT')), dateadd('hour',8, try_to_timestamp(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS AM PST'))) as utc_time1
    ,iff(substr(time, -3) = 'PDT',dateadd('hour',7, try_to_timestamp(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS AM PDT')), dateadd('hour',8, try_to_timestamp(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS AM PST')) ) as utc_time2
FROM VALUES
    ('2020-10-28 7:25:44 AM PDT'),
    ('2020-11-06 6:35:18 PM PST') 
    v(time);
```

which gives:

```
TIME                        UTC_TIME1             UTC_TIME2
2020-10-28 7:25:44 AM PDT   2020-10-28 14:25:44   2020-10-28 14:25:44
2020-11-06 6:35:18 PM PST   2020-11-07 02:35:18   2020-11-07 02:35:18
```

As Per my comment if you have more TIMEZONE you need to support, lets say New Zealand's two timeszones ;-) then a CASE would be more suitable

```
SELECT time
    ,substr(time, -4) as tz_str -- longer and NZxT is longer
    ,CASE
       WHEN tz_str = ' PDT' THEN dateadd('hour',7, try_to_timestamp_ntz(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS AM PDT'))
       WHEN tz_str = ' PST' THEN dateadd('hour',8, try_to_timestamp_ntz(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS AM PST'))
       WHEN tz_str = 'NZDT' THEN dateadd('hour',-13, try_to_timestamp_ntz(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS AM NZDT'))
       WHEN tz_str = 'NZST' THEN dateadd('hour',-12, try_to_timestamp_ntz(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS AM NZST'))
   END as utc_time
FROM VALUES
    ('2020-10-28 7:25:44 AM PDT'),
    ('2020-11-06 6:35:18 PM PST'),
    ('2021-04-23 2:45:44 PM NZST'),
    ('2021-01-23 2:45:44 PM NZDT')
    v(time);
```

OR you could use a regex to match up to the `AM/PM` part of the date time like in this [SO Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67202900/how-to-convert-long-verbal-datetime-to-timestamp-yy-mm-dd-hhmmss-in-snowflak/67203452#67203452), and have just one try_to_timestamp_ntz and just use the CASE to correct based of the suffix.

Comment: Wow this is a god-level solution. Will need to take time to understand how this all works. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: I understand it.. wow so brilliant. Cheers!

Comment: the the `IFF` version sort of expands out better if you had 4-5 timezones you need to support and then used a `CASE` statement.